# Ubuntu doesn't parse JSP/JSTL tags Spring MVC project

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, ubuntu, tags, jstl

I have a problem with making spring project on my new ubuntu. Few days ago I moved from windows 7 to ubuntu. Yesterday, I downloaded one of my first Spring project. It is really simple, few .jsp pages, one controller etc.

HERE IS THE LINK:https://github.com/azalut/spring

And my problem is:  When I run this project on my windows 7 OS - .jsp pages are normally read. In example: from ${juzer.name} tag I recieve the value of the "name" property.

However it looks different on my Ubuntu. (Earlier I had problems with making project from scratch so I decided to download that project). On ubuntu, when I enter some url, like: localhost:8080/home  - I recieve not-parsed JSP tags, in example: ${juzer.name} < just like that, in this form.

Ive no idea whats going on here, could anyone help me? ;) would be really grateful

Comment: Ubuntu has nothing to do with that. You probably deployed it under a different server.

Comment: omg you were right @JBNizet , on windows I was using tomcat 7.0.12 and on this version everything works fine, but on 7.0.53 (the latest 7.x version) it doesnt want to. do you know why?

Comment: No, sorry, I have no idea.